# How to disable making buckets public in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to deny that a Bucket can be made public in S3.

I know that I can track this by  [s3-bucket-public-write-prohibited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-public-write-prohibited.html) and
[s3-bucket-public-read-prohibited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-public-read-prohibited.html)

But these are rules to check if the buckets are compliant.

**How can I actually disable to make a public bucket?**

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You can choose permission while creating.

**Set permissions** (option 3 in the create bucket window)

**Option 2**

If created Follow the configuration document,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-bucket.html

**Option 3:**

Or you can define custom policy under, 
permission--> bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html

Comment: How can I disable that from the console a developer, would make the bucket public....these options do not prevent anybody for creating a public bucket.

Comment: You would use [Block S3 Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-bucket.html) and ensure that the developers do not have permission to change those settings.

Comment: While creating the developer role in IAM Management console give only AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess